# What design pattern is this?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

Several years ago, I used to create interfaces like this :

```
class Base
{
  public:
    virtual ~Base
    {
    }

    void foo()
    {
      doFoo();
    }

  private:
    virtual void doFoo() = 0;
};
```

then a derived would be :

```
class Derived : public Base
{
  public:
    virtual ~Derived()
    {
    }

  private:
    virtual void doFoo()
    {
    }
};
```

I am sure I saw this as a design pattern somewhere, but now I can not find it anywhere, and can not remember how it is called.

So, how is this design pattern called?

Comment: Please check the definition of `Derived` it surely isn't complete and the kind of inheritance used is actually important here.

Comment: Right. Fixed the example. sorry for confusion

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `foo` method shouldn't be virtual. And in this case the design pattern is called NVI - [non-virtual interface](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Non-Virtual_Interface)

Comment: -1 it's not a pattern from the GoF book. The Template Method pattern is more general and is part of the Gof Book.

Comment: @Stephane: So... ermm... if it's not in the GoF book, then it's not a pattern? :)))

Comment: @Stephane: WTF does GoF have to do with anything? It was not mentioned in the question even once. Other patterns exist that aren't in that one book, you know.

Comment: @Tomalak Yes, one can give 1500 names to patterns, and invent their own with slight differences. Your point of view. Not mine.

Comment: @Stephane: You seem to hold GoF as some kind of gold standard for design patterns. You're wrong. Read [Design pattern (computer science) on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern_%28computer_science%29) and note that the definition is _not_ "a pattern listed in the GoF book".

Comment: @Stephane: I fully agree that the template method is the generalization of nvi. But the OP's example is NVI, not its generalization. It's like if I asked you what kind of number 4 was, and you'd say it's a complex number...

Comment: @Armen, it's just because I would prefer the other answer to be topped. So I maintain my -1. I will remove it if the other one goes to the top. Though I am glad to learn that term "NVI" ;-).

Comment: Although the other answer is also correct, this is what I was looking for. thanks

Comment: @Stephane: Downvoting a correct andswer to push another answer up... doesn't seem very fair to me... but it's a free country, isn't it? :))

Comment: @Tomalak. The Gof book is simply my preferred computer sciences book ever. :-). And I like the fact it defines a vocabulary for experienced solutions. On the wikipedia page: "Template method Define the skeleton of an algorithm in an operation, deferring some steps to subclasses. Template method lets subclasses redefine certain steps of an algorithm without changing the algorithm's structure". Here we have only one step.

Comment: @Armen: Stephane doesn't appear to understand what up-/down-voting means.

Comment: @Stephane: That doesn't change the fact that you downvoted an answer that is _not wrong_, just because it's not discussed in your favourite book. That is not in the spirit of Stack Overflow. Please read the FAQ (there's a link at the top of every page).

Comment: I have my point of view of what a design pattern is. And I maintain it.

Comment: Design pattern define a restricted vocabulary. And what is amazing is that you don't even only once notice the downvotes of the other answer... that's is not community-wise :-)

Comment: @Armen: NVI is generally not described as a pattern, but as an idiom. Wikipedia has a good explanation of what an idiom is in the programming field: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_idiom One notable difference is that a programming idiom is generally tied to a language (or several), although the Wikipedia article note that design patterns can be thought of as idioms. In general, idioms are technical solutions while design patterns are high-level (functional) solutions. It does not make your answer incorrect though, since we can assume this difference was unknown to the OP.

Comment: @Matthieu M. I am trying to understand what you have edited, but the revision seems to be the same as the original text... Could you please explain? :)

Comment: @Stephane: It's a shame that your "point of view" doesn't match any existing documentation, or anyone else's opinion. Oh well.

Comment: @Armen: I had voted then removed my vote because of the controversy, as I wanted some time to think about it... and the engine would not let me upvote again (saying I had already cast my vote) unless the answer was edited, so I added a blank and upvoted...

Answer (score 8):

This is the [template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).  Relevant excerpt from Wikipedia:

> A template method defines the program
>   skeleton of an algorithm. One or more
>   of the algorithm steps can be
>   overridden by subclasses to allow
>   differing behaviors while ensuring
>   that the overarching algorithm is
>   still followed.

I've seen this pattern used a lot to "enforce" calling the base class implementation (which normally has to be done explicitly in the deriving class).

Comment: It's not the template method pattern, although it superficially resembles it.  As Armen Tsirunyan said, it's the non-virtual interface pattern.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? I think it is fair to say that NVI is just a special case of template methods, after reading the description on the [linked page](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Non-Virtual_Interface). Is there a reason why that would be a 'wrong' understanding?

Comment: +1 More than "superficially". It is a simple implementation of the Template Method Pattern, preciselly. One non virtual function calling a sequence of virtual function (here only one).

Comment: More C++ related and with a good rationale is http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm

Comment: @James: I had not heard of NVI, thanks, but I agree with @sehe and @Stephane.  From what I read at http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Non-Virtual_Interface, the template method pattern is NVI generalized, so the original example is the NVI form of the template method pattern.

Comment: +1: those downvotes seems a little harsh: I agree it could be the Template Method or the Non-Virtual Interface. They are very closely related.

Comment: @James: see http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm.  The mixup is that NVI is an idiom and template method is one of the GoF Patterns.  The link show it is related and not just a superficial resemblence.  However, this is just discussing semantics...

Comment: The NVI and the template method pattern are only superficially related.
The template method pattern defines the program skeleton of an
algorithm.  The virtual functions (private or protected) have no direct
relationship to the public functions defining the interface.  The NVI
pattern is used for PbC, has no implementation in the interface (the
base class), only validation code (pre- and post-conditions), and has
a one to one relationship between the public functions and the
non-public virtual functions.

Comment: @James: as I said on Armen's answer, NVI is an idiom, and whether we consider an idiom a design pattern is debatable. One notable difference is that a programming idiom is generally tied to a language (or several). In general, idioms are technical solutions while design patterns are high-level (functional) solutions. Given that this distinction is lost on most people, this response is perfectly fine as far as I am concerned. We may reproach it to be too broad in the C++ context, but it is indeed correct.

Comment: If you make the distinction between idiom:1 language, design pattern:more than one language, then NVI is an idiom (although I've used it in Java as well).  That's not the point, however.  The point is that NVI and the Template Method Pattern are two very distinct things, and the original code is *not* an example of the Template Method Pattern, for the reasons I've already explained (no program skeleton).